# FB.getLoginStatus() not firing

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0

Currently FB.getLoginStatus is not at all firing after the facebook changes with new SDK and OAuth 2.0.
We used to get the response in FB.getLoginStatus and call our callback function that in turn was redirecting 
the users to our facebook application.

Please help.

The code snippet -

```
FB.init({
        appId: '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIKey"]%>', // App ID
        //channelURL: 'xd_receiver.htm', // Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        oauth: true // enable OAuth 2.0
        //xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });
update_user_is_connected();
function update_user_is_connected() 
{
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
    {
        callback();
            });
}

function callback() {
    var fbURL = "http://apps.facebook.com/" + '<%=Suffix%>' + "/MyPage.aspx";
    eval("parent.location='" + fbURL + "'");

}
```

Now FB.getLoginStatus is not working.

Regards,
KK

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue and fixed it by adding `true` as a second parameter :

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)  {
         callback();
    },
    true);
```

This disables the cache and forces reloading. See [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered this error whilst trying to check whether the user is already logged in with Facebook as soon as the page finished loading.

If you're trying to do this, you need to wait for facebook sdk to finish loading, Make your call to your `checkLoginState()` method inside `window.fbAsyncInit` after FB.init().

Answer (score 0):

This code works very well with me to check login status and request login and fetch oauth info (Name, User Id, Token ... ) based on Java script SDK.

I have some recommendations which are that you have to make sure your application and channel file should be located within your domain which you have setup in your Facebook App settings.

Also make sure you have the div fb-root in your code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

As shown below
Hope this may help ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
                channelUrl : 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/channel.html',
                status     : true,
                cookie     : true,
                xfbml      : true,
                oauth      : true
            });

                var token = "";
                var userId = "";

                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {  // Get Login Status

                    if (response && response.authResponse) { // Check if User is Logged In

                        var token = response.authResponse.accessToken; // Get Token
                        var userId = response.authResponse.userID;     // Get User ID

                    } else {
                        //  alert("Not Auhtenticated");
                        FB.login(function(response) { // Promot User to Authenticate App
                            if (response && response.authResponse) {
                                var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                                var userId = response.authResponse.userID;
                            }
                        }, {scope: 'user_likes,friends_likes,publish_stream,read_friendlists,offline_access'}); // Scopes Example...
                    }
                });
            };

            //Load asynchronously
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxx";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the `window.fbAsyncInit` function.

```
FB.init({
  appId      : '321677491886687',
  cookie     : true,
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : '3.2'
});
```

I needed to change `3.2` to `v3.2`

Answer (score -1):

Kamal,

I believe you can fix your problem by replacing

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
{
    callback();
        });
```

with

```
FB.Event.Subscribe('auth.login', callback());
```

Regards

Comment: And how can I get the logged in user id,token etc. ?

Comment: But,why FB.getLoginStatus is not firing?I have already kept sandbox mode disabled.

Comment: in your callback function you can call FB.getLoginStatus and obtain all the info you need

Comment: The problem is FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { alert(1)}); is not working

Answer (score -2):

Make sure all you URLs are correct, I had the same problem while running locally but had the site URL pointing to the production website, once I corrected this, getLoginStatus worked all right.